# Let's Encrypt / Certbot in Google App Engine -> can't check challenge -> Forbidden 403

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

Using Google App Engine and Let's Encrypt or Certbot, I'm trying to issue a certificate to my web app, but when the challenge is to be tested, the file hosted in /.well-known/acme-challenge/ can't be acessed because (apparently of nginx configuration that prohibits access to dot paths), in other words, it gets a 403 - Forbidden page instead of the key.

I've already tried to change nginx.conf with this:

```
 location ^~ /.well-known/ {
      allow all;
    }
```

Restarted nginx service, but still, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Anyone running into this same issue, I recommend using Acme PHP which has another method for checking the ownership of the domain (DNS TXT). It worked like a charm and reaches out the same goal: https://acmephp.github.io/documentation/guides/dns-challenge.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an alias?

```
location ^~ /.well-known {
  allow all;
  auth_basic off;
  alias /path/to/.well-known/;
}
```